# List range is being taken as tuple rather than integers

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to fetch elements from a list as per following code:

"data" is a string containing some data from which i am taking out values of start and end offset.
I am then multiplying the start and end Offset by 4 to calculate `start,endOffsetAsPerPage`.

```
startOffset = data.split(",,")[1].split(":")[1];
endOffset = data.split(",,")[2].split(":")[1];
startOffsetAsPerPage = int(startOffset)*4;
endOffsetAsPerPage = int (endOffset)*4;  
FilteredData = CassandraData[int(startOffsetAsPerPage),int(endOffsetAsPerPage)];
```

While executing, i am facing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CassandraDataAPIResultValidator.py", line 55, in <module>
    FilteredData = CassandraData[int(startOffsetAsPerPage),int(endOffsetAsPerPage)];
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Can you please help here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slice your array as `int(startOffsetAsPerPage):int(endOffsetAsPerPage)`, not `int(startOffsetAsPerPage),int(endOffsetAsPerPage)`

Comment: `FilteredData = CassandraData[int(startOffsetAsPerPage)],CassandraData[int(endOffsetAsPerPage)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a comma:

```
FilteredData = CassandraData[int(startOffsetAsPerPage),int(endOffsetAsPerPage)]
#                                                     ^
```

A comma there makes it a tuple, not a slice.

Use a *colon* instead:

```
FilteredData = CassandraData[int(startOffsetAsPerPage):int(endOffsetAsPerPage)]
#                                                     ^
```

Note that Python doesn't need to use semicolons at the ends of lines.